# How to save image to file in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, discord.js

i am trying to upload an image to the chat and have the discord bot save the image on disk

i still don't know much about javascript but this is what i have.
I would like to solve this problem without using an external library

```js
message.attachments.forEach(a => {
   fs.writeFileSync(`./${a.name}`, a.file);
});
//this creates an undefined file

console.log(message.attachments.length);
//this prints undefined

const file = fs.createWriteStream("file.jpg");
const request = http.get(message.attachments[0].url, (response) => {
   response.pipe(file);
});
//this creates an empty file.jpg
```

Comment: `message.attachments` is a collection, not an array. Therefore, you should use `message.attachments.size`, `message.attachments.first()`, etc. If you'd like to make it an array, then do so (`message.attachments.array()`) and use that with the code above instead.